# Convert to gpk a KMZ layer with information that is connected to a server

Tags: qgis, layers, kml, geopackage, kmz

I need to use the information from a KMZ file, that is anchored to an online server, when I save the place on my local server and open it, it keeps connecting to the server preventing me from using the layer and I need to trim the layer.

Comment: What is the service the KMZ links to?  A KMZ is just a zip file. Unzip (may need to change file extension from .kmz to .zip), open doc.kml in a text editor and have a look.

Comment: is the CENAPRED server, when i try use in the Qgis project appeared the legend “invalid proveedor”

Comment: What is the full URL of the service the KMZ links to? How exactly did you try to add it to QGIS. Note, please edit your question to include this information, don't reply as a comment.